# Android computing with a math variables

Tags: java, android, arrays

Im really new to android development but I have a few knowledge with regards to java.

I have to develop an app where the concept is similar to a simple calculator but the difference is it only has 2 math operators its either addition or subtraction and there are  variables x and y involved. `2x+5x` is a possible input to the `EditText`. The problem is how to compute the result.

If it had been a simple `2+5`, the application can compute it. The main problem is, computing the equation with a variable `x` beside the number. I've been searching google for an answer but no luck at all.

I first get the values as string then split them into an array although I'm not sure if that's the correct way, then parse it into an int values, then loop each of them based on the length of the array I got from my `EditText` object.

here is the code for getting the values and splitting them into an array along with the computing the values inside the array:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"0");
            result1 +="0";
            break;

        case R.id.button5:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"1");
            result1 +="1";
            break;

        case R.id.button6:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"2");
            result1 +="2";
            break;

        case R.id.button7:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"3");
            result1 +="3";
            break;

        case R.id.button9:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"4");
            result1 +="4";
            break;

        case R.id.button10:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"5");
            result1 +="5";
            break;

        case R.id.button11:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"6");
            result1 +="6";
            break;

        case R.id.button13:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"7");
            result1 +="7";
            break;

        case R.id.button14:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"8");
            result1 +="8";
            break;

        case R.id.button15:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"9");
            result1 +="9";
            break;

        case R.id.button12:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"x");
            result1 +="x";
            break;
        case R.id.button16:
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"y");
            result1 +="y";
            break;
//here is the case for solving the equation 
        case R.id.button2: //equal sign
            result2 = result1;
            int sum = 0,nums;


                String[] g = input.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\+|x",",").split(",");

                for (int i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {

                        nums = Integer.parseInt(g[i]);
                        sum += nums;
                }
            answer.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            break;

        case R.id.button4://addition
            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"+");
            operator += "+";//addition

            break;
            case R.id.button8://subtraction

            input.setText(input.getText().toString()+"-");
            operator += "-";//subtraction

            break;



        case R.id.button17: //clear
            input.setText("");
            answer.setText("");
            result1 = "";
            result2= "";
            operator = "";
            finalresult = 0;
            break;
    }

}
```

here is my xml if in case its also an issue

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Calculator" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"

        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button17" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="
        android:layout_below="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Solve"

        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="x"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button14" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button14" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="y"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AC"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Enter Equation Here">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to do is to compute the algebraic linear equation and display the result with the character "x".. so simply using `.replaceAll()` to remove it is a no-no unless there is something we can do to simply erase them when computing then just bring them back after its been solve..

please help I can't seem to find an answer for this problem

Comment: I really need this to work guys please help me :(

Comment: Being more precise on what the problem is will help. Are you trying to create an equation calculator (`2x + 5x = 14`) ? Or you just want to scan for numbers and operators int the input text, ignoring everything else (`22x+abc3 = 25`) ?

Comment: yes you are very correct I'm developing an equation calculator..

Comment: the idea is similar to this link http://www.marblesoftwaresolutions.com

Comment: That's going to take some hard work, depending on complexity of equations you want to support. This may be a start : http: http://jeval.sourceforge.net/docs/api/net/sourceforge/jeval/EvaluationHelper.html

Comment: I know right? well the scope is pretty much a simple one
1. No other variables involve except for x and y 
2. No exponents involve
3. Just the very basic algebra no
advance things just the basic

Comment: why was it down voted? explanation please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't count as numbers are pressed and you don't even need separate functions to track anything special about what is pressed.

You should approach it this way:

Use a `TextWatcher` and `afterTextChanged` to parse the data after even key press if you need a result after each key press. Otherwise use a "calculate" button to perform the "calculation" when necessary.

To perform the "calculation" you should use `split` four times. Do the first set of splits based on the operators "+" and "-" to determine your operands. Then do a second set based on "x" and "y".

Then use the sets of tokens and indexes to identify if you have things like "21" vs "2x" or just "2" or "x". After you identify the types of tokens you have, you can sort through and apply the appropriate operations to "group" your variables and calculate your constant.

Also, in performing the "operators" on the variables, it should be noted that "-" is really addition of a negative number. In other words, the "-" operator is really addition of a negative operand.

Comment: sorry but do i need 3 sets of array here? 1 for the numbers 2 for the variables 3 for the operators is this correct?

Comment: Since you only have 2 variables and 2 operators, i don't think you "need" arrays unless you expect to extend the solution to other variables and operators